# Running Two C++ file in Bash script

Tags: bash

I wrote a bash script to run both client and server.
The code is written in cpp and *client* and *server* are executable.

```
$port=8008
$pack_rate=16     
echo "Starting server"
./server -p $port -n 512 -e 0.001
echo "Starting client"
./client -p $port -n 512 -l 16 -s localhost -r $pack_rate -d
echo "end"
```

In the above case, the client will send data packets to the server and the server will process it.
So, both the client and server should run at the same time.
I tried to run the script file, but as expected only

```
"Starting server"
```

is getting printed. So, *server* is running and server will not terminate until it receives 512 packets from the client. But *client* process can not start until server ends in the bash script.

So, is there any way by which I can run both the process simultaneously using single bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `&` add the end of the `./server` line, it will run the process in batch mode, and keep executing the rest of the script

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an &:

```
./server -p $port -n 512 -e 0.001 &
```

Thus, the script will not wait the end of the server program to continue.